# How do I access yahoo weather API Conditions and forecast json objects

Tags: json, api

Not sure whats wrong but i am not getting a value for id="hi" nor id="temp"

```
<p>Weather In: <span id="city"></span>,<span id="state"></span></p>
<p id="state"></p>
<p id="unit"></p>
<p id="hi"></p>
<p id="temp"></p>
<p>Wind Speed: <span id="speed"></span></p>

<script>
    var callbackFunction = function(data) {
    var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind;
    var location = data.query.results.channel.location;
    var units = data.query.results.channel.units;
    var forecast = data.query.results.channel.forecast;
    var condition = data.query.results.channel.item;

    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = location.city;
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = location.region;
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = wind.speed;
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = units.temperature;
    document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = forecast[0][0];
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = condition.condition.item;
    };
</script>
```

These are the JSON Objects im trying to access. They comprise the yahoo weather api response. I am having trouble accessing the forcast array and the object for temperature(conditions)

```
<!--Yahoo weather API being accessed/JSON Objects-->
    {
"query": {
"count": 1,
"created": "2017-01-22T16:53:36Z",
"lang": "en-US",
"results": {
"channel": {
"units": {
"distance": "mi",
"pressure": "in",
"speed": "mph",
"temperature": "F"
},
"title": "Yahoo! Weather - Nome, AK, US",
"link":                "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
"description": "Yahoo! Weather for Nome, AK, US",
"language": "en-us",
"lastBuildDate": "Sun, 22 Jan 2017 07:53 AM AKST",
"ttl": "60",
"location": {
"city": "Nome",
"country": "United States",
"region": " AK"
},
"wind": {
"chill": "-22",
"direction": "23",
"speed": "4"
},
"atmosphere": {
"humidity": "68",
"pressure": "1018.0",
"rising": "0",
"visibility": "16.1"
},
"astronomy": {
"sunrise": "11:15 am",
"sunset": "5:13 pm"
},
"image": {
"title": "Yahoo! Weather",
"width": "142",
"height": "18",
"link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
"url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
},
"item": {
"title": "Conditions for Nome, AK, US at 07:00 AM AKST",
"lat": "64.499474",
"long": "-165.405792",
"link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
"pubDate": "Sun, 22 Jan 2017 07:00 AM AKST",

<!-- how do i access this object????-->
"condition": {
"code": "29",
"date": "Sun, 22 Jan 2017 07:00 AM AKST",
"temp": "-22",
"text": "Partly Cloudy"
},
"forecast": [
{
"code": "30",
"date": "22 Jan 2017",
"day": "Sun",
"high": "-19",
"low": "-23",
"text": "Partly Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "28",
"date": "23 Jan 2017",
"day": "Mon",
"high": "-7",
"low": "-19",
"text": "Mostly Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "26",
"date": "24 Jan 2017",
"day": "Tue",
"high": "4",
"low": "-9",
"text": "Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "26",
"date": "25 Jan 2017",
"day": "Wed",
"high": "21",
"low": "5",
"text": "Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "28",
"date": "26 Jan 2017",
"day": "Thu",
"high": "22",
"low": "19",
"text": "Mostly Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "26",
"date": "27 Jan 2017",
"day": "Fri",
"high": "19",
"low": "18",
"text": "Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "26",
"date": "28 Jan 2017",
"day": "Sat",
"high": "19",
"low": "17",
"text": "Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "28",
"date": "29 Jan 2017",
"day": "Sun",
"high": "17",
"low": "12",
"text": "Mostly Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "28",
"date": "30 Jan 2017",
"day": "Mon",
"high": "20",
"low": "14",
"text": "Mostly Cloudy"
},
{
"code": "28",
"date": "31 Jan 2017",
"day": "Tue",
"high": "23",
"low": "13",
"text": "Mostly Cloudy"
}
],
"description": "<![CDATA[<img        src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/29.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Partly Cloudy\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Sun - Partly Cloudy. High: -19Low: -23\n<BR /> Mon - Mostly Cloudy. High: -7Low: -19\n<BR /> Tue - Cloudy. High: 4Low: -9\n<BR /> Wed - Cloudy. High: 21Low: 5\n<BR /> Thu - Mostly Cloudy. High: 22Low: 19\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>",
"guid": {
"isPermaLink": "false"
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is assigned to a variable data, you'd simply access them like so:

```
data.query.results.channel.item.condition.date // DATE
data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp // TEMPERATURE
data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text // CONDITIONS
```

Heres a quick fiddle using your JSON example https://jsfiddle.net/uop5qx5L/

sometimes it helps me determine how to access nested objects in my JSON data by using an online JSON visualizer / formatter [such as this one](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1e4c3b4fb4cf19727ee125f437b54798)

Comment: For tempreature var = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp; gives an error. It will accept var = data.query.results.channel.item; though

Comment: what specific error do you get?  try doing console.log(data.query.results.channel.item) and see what is returned , maybe that will help track down the issue.

Comment: im using code pen. Its not giving an error when i onsole log, just isnt doing anything

Comment: I can get it to work if the json objects are hard coded, but id like to be able to access the api dynamically.

Comment: in a case like this I'd start doing a console.log from the start... console.log(data), and see each level what I'm getting using console.log, until I find where it STOPS returning data... sometimes I've been able to solve the issue with data[0].query.results.channel.item.condition.temp, etc. etc.  Let me know what you find was the issue.